# Datagrid with filter row

Tags: wpf, datagrid

I am looking for some datagrid for my wpf application.

I already used devexpress. I am not so happy with the devexpress control.
So i wonna use now a free control. Do somebody know a free control.

Where you have a datagrid , that have on top a filter row.
Does somebody some a site with multiple free wpf controls?

Comment: This has been asked before, multiple times, you'd just need to find it...

Comment: I did already a search on the website. But didn't find any free solutions. Only some controls where you must pay.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's always best to use WPF standard controls, unless you are forced not to :)

There are several solutions to your problem, but in my opinion, the best solutions are the ones which uses only styles with the standard WPF `DataGrid` control without inventing a new inherited `DataGird` type or depending on another third-party control. The followings are the best solutions I found:

- Option 1: which I personally use: [Automatic WPF Toolkit DataGrid Filtering](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/WPF/DataGridFilterLibrary.aspx)
- Option 2:  [Auto-filter for Microsoft WPF DataGrid](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/WPF/wpffiltering.aspx)